# Не показывается список методов модуля в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, lua

Есть модуль:

```
local M = {}

--- find users by name
-- @param name string: user name
-- @return object with array of users
function M.find_users(name)
    return {users = {}};
end

return M
```

Используем:

```
local userapi = require("userapi")

pcall(userapi.find_users, name)
```

Всё работает, но в IDE нету подсказок методов. Т.е, когда я набираю `userapi.`, то нету выпадающего списка с доступными методами модуля.

Это проблема среды разработки или в LDoc что-то не дописал?
Как сделать, чтоб IDE отображала доступные методы модуля?